# RabbitMQ - Discard message if it is taking too long to process

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

Is there any way to make RabbitMQ discard the message if it is taking too long to process?

For example, if I have an email queue and the consumer script is taking too long to send the email, make it discard the message (put it in the dead letter exchange) and pick the next item in queue.

[image]

I am aware of `x-message-ttl` but that doesn't apply here because it is ignored once the message starts getting processed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way of doing what you want on the broker. For message to be moved to a dead letter exchange you will need to send `reject` or `nack` replies to the message which does not seem possible in your situation.

For example, you have `EmailSender` service and `EmailGenerator` service.
You could organize it this way:

`EmailGenerator` sends message with email.

`EmailSender` receives it.

When finished processing, `EmailSender` sends `sent confirmation` message to `EmailGenerator`.

`EmailGenerator` tracks state of what have been successfully sent so far.
If `EmailGenerator` had not received `sent confirmation` message for a particular email within X seconds, it resends the corresponding email message.